# Different icon opacity

Tags: css

What I have is good.
Only problem is that I want the image `sign` to have `opacity: 0.3` upon `hover` and the `star` to have `opacity: 1`, meaning full black colour upon `hover`. Now it seems that the `star` gets the `opacity` partly from the image `sign` and that is not wanted (you see the `star` is greyish. How to fix?

```css
.div:hover .sign {
  opacity: .3;
}
.div:hover > .sign::before {
  opacity: 1;
}

.div .sign {
  -webkit-transition: all 3.0s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 3.0s ease;
  -o-transition: all 3.0s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 3.0s ease;
  transition: all 3.0s ease;
  position: relative;
}

.div .sign::before {
  content: '\2605';
  font-family: "fontello";
  font-size: 5em;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  backface-visibility: hidden:
  -webkit-transition: all 3.0s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 3.0s ease;
  -o-transition: all 3.0s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 3.0s ease;
  transition: all 3.0s ease;
}

.div .sign {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
.div .sign img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="div">
    <div class="sign">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't apply the `0.3` of opacity to the `.sign` div because it will also affect the star since this one is a part of its content. Target the image instead:

```css
.div:hover .sign img {
  opacity: .3;
}

.div:hover>.sign::before {
  opacity: 1;
}

.div .sign img {
  transition: all 3.0s ease;
}

.div .sign::before {
  content: '\2605';
  font-family: "fontello";
  font-size: 5em;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  transition: all 3.0s ease;
}

.div .sign {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
}

.div .sign img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="div">
    <div class="sign">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that solved it, thanks a lot. I accept your answer in 4 minutes.

Comment: also, take note that the star is *under* the image if you use ::before, and *on* the image if you use ::after

Comment: @Neil we can simply play with z-index if we need to change the order ;) btw I don't think it's an issue here, I guess it's intended

Comment: oh yes, i was just pointing out to charliepie, but commented on yours since you were faster than me ;)